# Can I combine the + and - output of two different DC/DC converters or would that short the components?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I have two DC/DC power supplies powered from the same +48 V and GND rail. The first power supply generates 12 V out of the 48 V ([DDR-480C-12](https://storage.googleapis.com/aho-proconnecting-shopware-prod/media/pdf/6a/e7/c1/DDR-480-spec.pdf)). Now I want to have also -12 V available. Is it enough to connect the +Vo - Output from the ([DDR-15L-12](https://docs.rs-online.com/9f83/0900766b8165c19b.pdf)) to the -Vo of the first power supply or do I short something out? Is it good practice to ground the point where I connect +Vo and -Vo?

I am new to this topic, and I also searched through older posts but could not answer my question. I don't want to build any voltage dividers, I need to draw some power hence the industrial power supplies.

Comment: That works since they are isolated.

Comment: Thank you Sir, for the quick answer! Should I also ground the "0V" rail on the secondary side? Or  is this not so common?

Comment: Remember gnd = 0V , why would you want to connect 0V to earth ground? If needed , yes, if not then it is floating, but more prone to radiated noise without protection. So it depends on interference and wiring.

Comment: @bariumborat A diagram would be nice, also there is a circuit tool to draw them if you edit your answer

Comment: VotageSpike means [edit] your question. Only put answers in the Your Answer box - if you figured out your own answer to the question.

Comment: @bariumborat Connecting output to earth would defeat the strong isolation these guys have taken pains to design and would in fact cook your 12V PSU. But if you meant "ground" as in connect to GND plane of whatever device this is connected to, yes absolutely. Note that given this is a DC/DC supply, it is NOT a given there is isolation between input and output. Albeit in industrial modules isolation is probably pretty common.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 There's a long standing division on between not connecting device GND to earth and not doing it.. That is, for DC powered devices, for offlline supplies obviously not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect two power supplies with isolated outputs in this manner to get a positive and a negative rail:

[image]

Comment: Emphasis on the "with isolation"!

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!